# checkbox value is always true

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

in my mvc application i have a checkbox. but dont know why its value is always true. pls help

my view page

```
<div id="maindiv">
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.status)%>
<%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.status)%>
</div>
```

and the script is here how i am getting the value TRUE always

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#status').change(function () {
       alert(" active " + $('#status').val());
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use instead:

```
var status = ( $("#status").attr("checked") ? 'checked' : 'unchecked' );
alert(" active " + status);
```

**Explanation:**
you were reading the value of the checkbox which is always true, you need to check whether its `checked attribute` is checked or unchecked.
I used the ternary operator to check check whether it's checked or not
You could have also used `$("#status").is(":checked")` but it is slower.

Comment: thnx for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#status').change(function () {
   alert(" active " + this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this answer by Jab because it works.

```
var myValue = $("#status").is(":checked");
```

If checked, myValue = true, else myValue = false.